# XSD Define ENUM with multiple values

Tags: java, xsd

I would like to have an enum defined via XSD which looks like this:

```
    public enum Coin { 
             @XmlEnumValue("1") PENNY(1),
             @XmlEnumValue("5") NICKEL(5),
             @XmlEnumValue("10") DIME(10),
             @XmlEnumValue("25") QUARTER(25) 
   }
```

The [Oracle-description](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlEnumValue.html) details this sampe; but I cannot see there where the ENUMs "PENNY", "NICKEL" etc come from in this example.

```
 <!-- Example: XML Schema fragment -->
     <xs:simpleType name="Coin">
       <xs:restriction base="xs:int">
         <xs:enumeration value="1"/>
         <xs:enumeration value="5"/>
         <xs:enumeration value="10"/>
         <xs:enumeration value="25"/>
       </xs:restriction>
     </xs:simpleType>
```

Comment: its kind of a mapping as i understand it

Answer (score 0):

As it appears in the [Oracle description](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlEnumValue.html) the java enum sample code is not complete (it is lacking the private parameterized constructor of the enum which allows the `PENNY(1)` type of declaration) but serves to illustrate the purpose of mapping between the xsd and the java using the value parameter passed through the `@XmlEnumValue` annotation

So simply:

- PENNY maps to `<xs:enumeration value="1"/>` via the annotation `@XmlEnumValue("1")` the `PENNY(1)` type of declaration is an invocation of a parameterized constructor allowing you to save the value in a field of the enum
- NICKEL maps to `<xs:enumeration value="5"/>` via the annotation `@XmlEnumValue("5")` the `PENNY(5)` type of declaration is an invocation of a parameterized constructor allowing you to save the value in a field of the enum

The same logic applies to the other values as well

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I was aware that the Oracle sample is not complete - it was meant to show the use of the annotation.

What I'm looking for is a working xsd-sample to get the described enum. I did not find another sample, so I used this to show what I want. But it seems I was clear enough